# Error when run !make and !rm darknet on google colab

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, yolov4

I am training a model using yolov4 and I use google colab for training. When I run

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Test_self_train_yolo_v4/darknet
!rm darknet
!make
```

I got errors:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Test_self_train_yolo_v4/darknet
rm: cannot remove 'darknet': No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/cuda.o', needed by 'libdarknet.so'.  Stop.
```

I do not understand why I got error no such file or directory. Can anyone explain or help me? Thank you so much.

[image: Error in step 8]

Comment: The output of `rm` says that there's nothing called `darknet` to delete. So it's fine, just proceed with `make clean;make` in the next cell

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed my errors

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi any idea why i am getting darknet/libdarknet.so: cannot open shared object file while using from darknet import performDetect as scan or import darknet